# How to find all combinations of variadic typelist in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I would like to write a C++ metafunction that given a list of types, with no duplicated elements, generate all the possible sublists with size `sizeof...(list) - 1`.

**Update**: I am looking for a generic implementation of the metafunction `find_all`, as defined below. The implementation I have for now just specializes (hard coded) the result for lists of up to 5 elements, which is obviously not generic at all.

Below some simple definitions and an example:

Given a container that stores a list of types:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct type_list{};
```

And an "instance" of it:

```
struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C{};

using ABC = type_list<A, B, C>::type;
```

And using the metafunction, called `find_all`:

```
using found_result = find_all<ABC>;
```

The result should be:

```
using expected_result = type_list<
  type_list<A, B>,
  type_list<A, C>,
  type_list<B, C>
>;

static_assert(
  std::is_same<
    expected_result,
    found_result
  >::value, "");
```

It's acceptable if the elements in the resulting sublists or the sublists themselves are in a different order provided that the ordering is deterministic. So the following result is also valid, for instance:

```
using another_possible_expected_result = type_list<
  type_list<B, A>,
  type_list<B, C>
  type_list<C, A>,
>;
```

I am using C++11 (clang 6.0, Linux x86_64), but it would be ok using C++14.

If it helps, I am also using the `brigand` metaprogramming library, which has useful functions for list/set handling, but I accept answers that use other libraries as well.

Comment: Did you try implementing it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, I tried but could not go beyond the trivial cases of a list with  zero or one elements

Comment: Do you have an algorithm ? If not, you should choose a functional one.  Many are indexed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n

Comment: @MichaelDoubez This is a different problem

Comment: Really ? You are not trying to find all the combinaison of size k=n-1 in a set of size n ?

Comment: This may be used for inspiration : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134856/views-and-ranges-for-tuple-like-objects (make_tuple_view for example)

Comment: @MichaelDoubez Yes, really. This is a specific case of that problem, but since it is a specific case, it's a different enough problem than an entirely different algorithm is reasonable

Comment: @Justin. Ah! Yes, you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Brigand, so I used [Kvasir::mpl](https://github.com/kvasir-io/mpl) instead. At any rate, the algorithm should be transferable to any of the TMP libraries out there:

Given the type list `[a0, a1, ..., aN]`, produce the list:

```
[a1, a2, a3, ..., aN]
[a0, a2, a3, ..., aN]
[a0, a1, a3, ..., aN]
...
[a0, a1, a2, ..., aN-1]
```

In other words, the `I`th element of the resulting list is the original list with the `I`th element removed.

---

In code with Kvasir::mpl:

```
namespace mpl = kvasir::mpl;

// Produce a list of indices into the original list
template <typename C = mpl::listify>
using indices = mpl::size<mpl::make_int_sequence<C>>;

// Given a list, produce a list of functions which, when evaluated on the original list,
// would erase the corresponding element.
template <typename C = mpl::listify>
using erase_each_index = indices< // given the indices,
    mpl::transform<               // transform each index by
        mpl::cfe<mpl::erase>,     // producing mpl::erase<Index>
        C
    >
>;

template <typename C = mpl::identity>
using listify = mpl::cfe<mpl::list, C>;

template <typename Fn, typename Args>
using eager_call = mpl::call<
    mpl::unpack<Fn>,
    Args
>;

template <typename C = mpl::listify>
using penultimate_sized_sublists =  mpl::fork< // each path takes the original list
    // 1. produce a list of functions which erase their index
    erase_each_index<>,
    // 2. produce the original list, wrapped in an extra list
    listify<listify<>>,
    // Both 1 and 2 are passed here. We perform a cartesian product (that's why
    // we wrapped 2 in an extra list) to put the arguments together with the functions
    mpl::product<
        // Evaluate each function against the entire list
        mpl::cfe<eager_call>
    >
>;
```

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/A4SJYR):

```
static_assert(
    std::is_same<
        mpl::call<
            mpl::unpack<penultimate_sized_sublists<>>,
            mpl::list<A, B, C>
        >,
        mpl::list<
            mpl::list<B, C>,
            mpl::list<A, C>,
            mpl::list<A, B>
        >
    >::value,
    ""
);
```

Comment: Thank you for both quick and useful answers. I will also have a look at Kvasir, but it seems to be very similar to Brigand as both projects share some same authors/contributors.

Comment: @LeandroSantiago Saying "thank you" in comments is unnecessary, although appreciated :-). If you want to thank someone for writing a good / useful answer, [the best thing to do is to upvote it or accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126184/218012).

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use C++14 and Boost, the algorithm in my other answer can be easily implemented with [Boost Hana](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/):

```
#include <utility>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

template <typename Tup>
constexpr auto penultimate_sized_sublists(Tup types)
{
    constexpr auto size = hana::size(types);
    // hana::range is unusable with hana::transform,
    // hence the conversion to a hana::tuple
    constexpr auto indices = hana::to_tuple(hana::make_range(hana::size_c<0>, size));

    return hana::transform(indices, [&](auto index) {
        return hana::remove_at(types, index);
    });
}
```

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/ZeLV1v)